# PHP: Replace all floats in a string to two decimal places

Tags: php, regex

If I have a string: "*This number 1.2345 and this is another 6.7891224342*" how would I get it to be "*This number 1.23 and this is another 6.78*"

I tried the following but getting zeros:

```
$input_lines = $inc['abstractions'];
$input_lines = preg_replace("/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/m", round("$1", 2), $input_lines);
```

Any advice?

Comment: (double) $input_lines

Comment: `preg_replace('~\d\.\d{2}\K\d+~', '', $s)` if you do not need to round anything. You say you want to get `6.78` for `6.7891224342`, are you sure you do not expect `6.79`? Else, use [`preg_replace_callback('~\d+\.\d+~', function($m) {return round($m[0], 2);}, $s)`](http://rextester.com/ULID8955).

Comment: Round doesn't cut at some points. It rounds.

Comment: @Wiktor please post your captureless solution as an answer.

Comment: @pee2pee So what is the actual required behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Round doesn't cut at some points. It rounds. You can't either use `round` within replacement string. You have to use `preg_replace_callback` or look for the right way:

```
preg_replace('~(\d\.\d\d)\d+~', '$1',  $input_lines);
```

Note: you don't need `m` flag.

I'm not sure about your own pattern but having it adopted:

```
preg_replace('~(\.\d\d)\d+~', '$1',  $input_lines);
```